# Are there BBP formulas for all computable numbers?

Tags: computability

A BBP algorithm is a formula with the following form where $b \in \mathbb Z$, $b \ge 2$, and $p(k)$ and $q(k)$ are polynomials in $k$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b^k}\frac{p(k)}{q(k)}$$
There are known BBP formulas for many computable numbers and it is easy to prove that any number with a BBP formula is computable.

Obviously all rationals have BBP formulas, let $n$ equal the length of the period in base $b$ and let $q(k)=1$ and $p(k) = \lfloor b^n\frac{p}{q}\rfloor$

I don't believe that there is a general form like that for all computable reals, i.e. you cannot given a definition of an irrational $\alpha$ derive $b$,$p(k)$,$q(k)$, but is it true that one exists for all computable numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use diagonalization to construct a computable real which is not of this form. Fix some enumeration of all triplets $(b,p,q)$. I will describe a process that generates binary digits of a real number.

The process goes over all triplets $(b,p,q)$ in the fixed order. Suppose that it's time to handle $(b_i,p_i,q_i)$, and that currently we have generated the digits $\beta_1 \dots \beta_n$. The process evaluates the corresponding sum $S(b,p,q)$ to such a precision that the first $n+1$ binary digits can be gleaned for it. It outputs $\beta_{n+1}$ so as not to equal to $S(b,p,q)$.

The argument as stated is not 100% correct, and I'm leaving it to the reader to discover where I cheated and to fix the proof.

Comment: I didn't think diagonalization worked with countable sets?

Comment: On the contrary, diagonalization works *only* for countable sets.

Comment: I thought it could only be used to prove that one set is countable and the other isn't.

Comment: No, it's a general technique which is very useful in set theory, recursion theory, complexity theory, and probably many other areas.

Comment: To me, your cheat seems to be that enumerating $(b,p,q)$ is not the same as enumerating the set of numbers $S(b,p,q)$. You're not making sure the "new" number is not on the list.

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos There is absolutely no need to assume that the mapping $(b,p,q) \mapsto S(b,p,q)$ is injective. In fact, there are diagonalization arguments in which you repeat every element infinitely many times on purpose.

Comment: I believe the cheat is that he doesn't prove the new $\beta_{n+1}$ is computable

Comment: There are actually two related issues: (1) dyadic integers have two binary representations, (2) if $S(b,p,q)$ is rational then it's not clear that you can really compute all the digits (perhaps you can). But these difficulties don't seem insurmountable. Ignoring the last issue, $\beta_{n+1}$ is definitely computable.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus as a secondary question would this argument apply to spigot algorithms in general too or is it just applicable to BBP type formulas?

Comment: The same argument should apply to every enumerable set of spigot algorithms.